# Select Specific columns from multiple Table with with() and select ()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables `test` and `goals`. One goal has many tests. I would like to fetch data like below.

```
$tests = test::with('goals')
                ->where('Goal_id', $goal_id)
                ->select('test.id as id','goals.Goal_id as goal_id','test.mode as mode')
                ->get();
```

But I am getting error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'goals.Goal_id' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goals relation is being eager loaded in a separate query so you will not have access to `goals.Goal_id` in your main query builder, instead you can modify your `with()` clause to pick specific columns from eager loaded relation as `with('goals:Goal_id,another_column')`

```
$tests = test::with('goals:Goal_id')
                ->where('Goal_id', $goal_id)
                ->select(['test.id as id','test.mode as mode'])
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should  work:

```
 $tests = DB::table('test')
        ->select(['test.id as id', 'goals.Goal_id as goal_id', 'test.mode as mode'])
        ->join('goals', 'goals.id', '=', 'test.goal_id')
        ->where('Goal_id', $goal_id)
        ->get();
```